# Как узнать, куда перенаправляет запрос?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Вот пример кода:

```
import request

urrl = 'http://ali.pub/3afchl'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}

req = requests.post(urrl, headers=headers)
print(req)
```

в ответ получаю `<Response [403]>`.

Как узнать перенаправление ссылки без блокировки?

Comment: Статус 403 - это не перенаправление, а "доступ запрещён".

Comment: я знаю, а почему он возникает? Все же должно работать?

Comment: Причин может быть множество, но скорее всего срабатывает защита от парсеров.

Comment: Интересно, что когда запускаю код на пк все работает, а вот когда код исполняется на сервере выходит ошибка 403 и только с ссылками ali.pub

Comment: Вероятно, ali.pub блокирует запросы с вашего сервера или диапазона адресов хостера.

Comment: Может, вы знаете как обойти блокировку?

Comment: HTTP прокси ну или тор

Comment: @trauer для начала надо выяснить принципы, по которым она работает, а потом уже искать пути обхода.

Comment: Мне все таки кажется, что http прокси поможет. Тогда, не подскажите как встроить его в мой код?

Answer (score 1):

В библиотеке `requests` у объекта `Response` есть метод `history`, его и используйте.

Такой код:

```py
import requests


url = 'http://ali.pub/3afchl'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
for i, each in enumerate(r.history, 1):
    print(f'{i} {each.status_code} {each.url}')
```

выведет список статусов и url-ов редиректа, если он был:

```
1 301 http://ali.pub/3afchl
2 302 https://ali.pub/3afchl
3 302 http://cooldeal.by/redirect/cpa/o/ae0a7d378 ...
4 301 http://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_bXnaEwc?af ...
5 302 https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_bXnaEwc?a ...
6 302 https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32976474169 ...
7 302 https://aliexpress.ru/item/32976474169.html ...
8 302 https://login.aliexpress.com/sync_cookie_re ...
9 302 https://login.aliexpress.ru/sync_cookie_wri ...
```

ps url обрезаны ... т.к. они супермегадлинные

pps запрос на ali.pub должен быть get